# SwaggerUi REST methods - methods produces and consumes exactly the same mime-types

Tags: java, rest, swagger-ui

I'm trying to create a REST methodes with swaggeUI.

A method that seach for User by id and another one by firstName, as follows:

```
@Produces( { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON } )
    @Path( "/{firstName}" )
    @GET
    @ApiOperation( value = "Find User by e-mail", notes = "Find User by e-mail", response = User.class )
    @ApiResponses( {
        @ApiResponse( code = 404, message = "User with such e-mail doesn't exists" )             
    } )
    public User getUserByFirstName( @ApiParam( value = "E-Mail address to lookup for", required = true ) @PathParam( "email" ) final String email ); 


@GET
    @Path("/{userId}")
    @Nullable
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    User getUserById(@Nonnull @PathParam("userId") Long userId);
```

when building the code i got this error:

> Following issues have been detected:  WARNING: A resource model has
>   ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP method GET and input
>   mime-types as defined by"@Consumes" and "@Produces" annotations at
>   Java methods User getUserByFirstName(java.lang.String) and public
>   abstract User getUserById(java.lang.Long) at matching regular
>   expression /([^/]+). These two methods produces and consumes exactly
>   the same mime-types and therefore their invocation as a resource
>   methods will always fail. WARNING: The (sub)resource method indexUsers
>   in UserService contains empty path annotation.

I'm new with REST , i need a help in order to fix this issus.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your @Path definitions.  It's not able to tell whether a Long should be a number or the String {firstname} could be a Long.

Try :

```
@Path("/name/{firstname}")
....
@Path("/id/{userid}")
```